# selecting an element with css selector python

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I am trying to select an element in selenium using python and need some help with css selector. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="grid x5" id="grid">
        <div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:92"></span>8</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:77"></span>23</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:93"></span>7</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:99"></span>1</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:80"></span>20</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:76"></span>24</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:83"></span>17</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:94"></span>6</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:87"></span>13</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:95"></span>5</div>
        <div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:78"></span>22</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:98"></span>2</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:82"></span>18</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:79"></span>21</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:89"></span>11</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:91"></span>9</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:85"></span>15</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:90"></span>10</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:81"></span>19</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:96"></span>4</div>
        <div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:97"></span>3</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:75"></span>25</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:88"></span>12</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:84"></span>16</div><div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:86"></span>14</div>
    </div>
```

One thing I can see is that in style="z-index:92" --> the 100 - z-index is the number being displayed. Not sure how this helps.

if I trying to using selenium and click on the number 1 - 25 using the code above, how would I go about do it with the HTML code presented above?

[Added a picture of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcrDH.png)

Thanks for you help!

Comment: You can select all the div inside div with id="grid". You can do this with driver.find_element_by_css_selector( "#grid > div") . Now,  you can iterate these elements , check their  innerText attribute using get_attribute("innerText") on webelement and click them if retrieved innerText attribute value is 1-25.

Comment: @Nish26 I follow till css_selector, not sure how to iterate these elements:        el1 = 
      webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("#grid > div").get_attribute("innerText") gets me only the first element? Do you mind expanding?

Comment: which 1-25 number you are trying to click? "z-index:95" or </span>8</div>

Comment: @theGuy </span>8</div>. I added a picture of how it looks.

Comment: zzzscore.com hhhh!

Comment: @user11750176 Ya :) - I was trying to impress some friends with a very 'unreasonable' score

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text 1-25 is contained in div tag, you can try:

```
#xpath
element_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@style,'opacity')]")# to find all div elements with style= "opacity: 1;"

#css selector
#element_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[style^=opacity]") # to match divs containing style attribute starting with opacity

for items in element_list:
    print (items.text)  #to print out element text
    if (items.text) in range(1, 25):
    # do your click action here
```

Comment: this is perfect! If I had to click the numbers in sequence, i.e click 1, click 2, click 3 ..., would there by any change?

Comment: @vay , its bit tricky as those elements can be stored at random location in list. You will have to either find the location of the elements first or sort the list items in sequence.