# Is there any way to locate this button (if it is a button) and click on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to click on some buttons of an online game consecutively. Taking a look at the [game](http://zzzscore.com/1to50/en/?ts=1584634069744#) could be helpful.
Here's a part of the main html relating to the buttons:

```
<div class="grid x5" id="grid">
    <div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:92"></span>1</div> #⬅Each of this lines are a button.
    <div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:92"></span>2</div>
    <div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:92"></span>3</div>
    <div style="opacity: 1;"><span class="box" style="z-index:92"></span>4</div>
</div>
```

The best I've got so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://zzzscore.com/1to50/en/')

wave_info = [[25, "//div[contains(@style, 'opacity')]"], [50, "//div[contains(@style, 'opacity')]"]]


n = 1
for wave in wave_info:
    grid_elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(wave[1])
    while n <= wave[0]:
        for item in grid_elements:
            if int(item.text) == n:
                item.click()
                n += 1
```

The code above works well, but after clicking on 27 buttons (and sometimes 28 buttons) it shows the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Parsa\Desktop\python\2.py", line 18, in <module>
    if int(item.text) == n:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

There is a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429771/selecting-an-element-with-css-selector-python) but I didn't understand it well.
Your early response in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How are we supposed to test this? Share all your code and check your chromedriver configuration.

Comment: @Hatt I just did it.

Answer (score 0):

### Error

The error you are receiving is being thrown at the final stage of the game when the boxes/buttons start disappearing. Once a box disappears calling `item.text` will return `None` which cannot be converted to an `int`.

### Solution

```
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

wave_info = [[25, "//div[contains(@style, 'opacity')]"], [50, "//div[contains(@class, 'second')]"]]
time.sleep(2)
n = 1
for wave in wave_info:
    time.sleep(.1)
    grid_elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(wave[1])
    while n <= wave[0]:
        for item in grid_elements:
            try:
                if int(item.text) == n:
                    item.click()
                    n += 1
            except ValueError:
                continue
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                break
```

### Explanation

Time is imported and `time.sleep(2)` is called to allow the page time to fully load before we begin interacting with it. The `time.sleep(.1)` at the beginning of the loop allows for the grid elements to fully load in-between the first and second wave(the transition between the first 25 and last 25 elements). All the elements that we are meant to click in the game share the same style, and this is taken advantage of in the solution above. All of the elements are found and saved in one line `grid_elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(wave[1])`. The elements are then looped through and are clicked when their value matches the number we are searching for. This minimizes the amount of clicks we actually have to do to 50 compared to clicking every element and hoping you have clicked the right one. This comparison takes place in a try except block incase a `ValueError` is thrown meaning that the `item.text` returned `None`. The other except terminates the inner for loop after the 50th element has been clicked. Because the page changes and the elements cease to exist after you click the 50th element, a `StaleElementReferenceException` is thrown when you attempt to click one of these elements. When the error is thrown we know the game is over because the page has changed meaning we can break the inner for loop. The outer two loops will automatically end because `n` will equal 51 and the entire `wave_info` array will have been looped through. If either error is thrown then the code will not be halted.

Comment: @Pautodidactic oops I made a mistake in my solution. There were multiple mistakes in the code you posted above, check the edit

Comment: string object has no attribute click

Comment: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'item'

Comment: I it works but after clicking on a number of buttons it shows this: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: the same result

Comment: Can you update the question with the new error and where is occurring along with the number the error is thrown on?

Comment: updated. I think you should delete your answer then or update it.

Comment: Solved it, I finally got time to test in my IDE. I believe the issue was that the program was running faster than it could load the CSS elements causing it to miss the last element during the transition. In short you have to add a sleep to the code and this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more elegant way to do so:

```
x = range(1, 51)
for number in x:
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[text()= "' + str(number) + '"]')
    element.click()
```

Comment: Although it finishes the game in about 11 seconds and it is very fast, I wonder if there is a faster script.

Comment: @Pautodidactic No idea

Comment: @Pautodidactic I think you should try another programming language.

Comment: @user13090170 I fixed my solution above, It can solve it in about 6 seconds because it is not constantly clicking

Comment: :( you deleted your account